# Why wont Chrome go to the background?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I have a problem with my Chrome browser, where it does not go the background, if you were to click on a separate window that is then supposed to come to the foreground.

With any other applications, this foreground/background business works just fine, so I know its not an OS issue. What can possibly be the cause/fix for this?

I am using Chrome version: "20.0.1132.57 m" (lastest) and my OS is Windows 7.

P.S. I am also having a hard time googling the issue, as it is not clear to me how best to describe the problem to google.

Thanks!

Comment: The only topmost/always-on-top extension that I can find is [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-top-it/jheacplmldofkoakhdajanmdfephkbln), so unless you were using that, then something else was going on. I don’t suppose it’s still happening is it?

Comment: @Synetech Sorry for the delay in replying to you. Yes, I resolved the problem a while back, but without re-installing. To be honest I do not remember what it was, although I vaguely remember it being related to some program Win-7 was automatically running that I removed.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I would do is uninstall chrome, and then reinstall. Have you tried doing this?

Comment: Yeah, I have already tried, but no dice.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked your add-ons and maybe tried deactivating the them one by one?

Also, you can start the Chrome Task Manager and then right click the title bar and see if you got the 'Always on top'-feature selected there.

Comment: Hmm, I didnt think the add-ons would matter, but I will try it.

Comment: That option only affects the Chrome Task Manager, not regular browser windows.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Settings → Advanced Settings* and click `[Reset browser settings]`; then re-enable your extensions and put all other settings back to where they were.